# To send message from one device to another with the help of Html5

Tags: android, html, sms

I want to send the message or sms from one device to another with the help of html5.The message should be sent on multiple devices in the group.

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm. I think you're a bit confused about what you're trying to do.

if you want to create a chat room in which you send information from one device to many different devices, you want to use [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/) or create your own server to handle [C2DM](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/).

Comment: I want to send the sms from my device to perticular group of devices using html5. Is it possible ?

Comment: how exactly do you think the set list of devices will know when you published the message? C2DM is your thing, pubnub already implements this

Comment: can we create the list of devices to send the message to them.And C2DM will work for my requirement ?

Comment: yes, that happens on the server side and is your job to handle

Comment: But here it will not go to all the devices, if i am wrong then can u please give me some links